# How to squeeze a complete image into a given Canvas size?

Tags: image, python-2.7, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I have an image of a bit large size (470 x 580)px.

I want to place this image in a 4x4 Canvas.

I do the following - but it doesnot squeeze the complete image into the canvas, it just crops the canvas size from the image and display it here.

```
from Tkinter import *
import ttk

class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)

        self.createWidgets(master)


    def createWidgets(self, master):

        master.title("Login - AHPS")
        self.mainframe = ttk.Frame(master, padding=(5,5,12,12))
        self.mainframe.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=(W, N, E, S) )

        self.img = PhotoImage(file='image.gif')
        self.welcomeImage = Canvas(self.mainframe)
        self.welcomeImage.create_image(0, 0, image=self.img, anchor=NW)
        self.welcomeImage.iamge = self.img

        self.welcomeImage.grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=4, columnspan=4, sticky=(W, N, E, S))


root = Tk()
app = Application(master=root)
app.mainloop()
```

How can I squeeze the complete image into this canvas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [image resize under PhotoImage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6582387/image-resize-under-photoimage)

Comment: You want a 470 pixel by 580 pixel image to appear in a 4 pixel by 4 pixel canvas?

Comment: Get the `pillow` package to do image manipulation.  It has an ImageTk function to make tk images directly from its internal format, without having to same the new image to disk.