# Make image full screen with PhotoImage

Tags: python, tkinter, photoimage

I've tried this but it doesn't help: [Image resize under PhotoImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6582387/image-resize-under-photoimage)

I already have this:

```
import tkinter
root = tkinter.Tk()
root.attributes("-fullscreen", True)
photo = tkinter.PhotoImage(file="image.gif")
img1 = tkinter.Label(root, image = photo)
img1.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

This works but my image doesn't take up the full screen and I wanted to know how to resize it to full screen.

Comment: Did you try what was in the question you linked to (calling the `zoom` method)? If not, why not? If so, please show what you tried. However, in case you don't know, images won't resize smoothly -- you can double or triple the size, but you won't be able to make it exactly fit the screen dimensions unless the size is already some multiple of the screen.

Comment: @BryanOakley Thanks. Do you thinks I should use PIL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realised it is not possible to do this and I will try to use PIL. Thanks to [@BryanOakley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7432/bryan-oakley) for helping me with this question.