# Reading an image from a URL, resizing it and applying antialiasing

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library, image-resizing, antialiasing

I'm trying to resize and apply antialiasing to an image I previously displayed in Tkinter. I'm reading it from a url. The problem is, I opened the image with tkinter.PhotoImage, and the resize() function I need is in PIL.Image. I'd like to know if there's a way to convert from one to another, or some other way I can resolve this issue.

Here's the code:

```
import tkinter
from urllib.request import urlopen
import base64
from PIL import Image

window = tkinter.Tk()

url = "https://s.yimg.com/os/weather/1.0.1/shadow_icon/60x60/partly_cloudy_night@2x.png"
b64_data = base64.encodestring(urlopen(url).read())
image = tkinter.PhotoImage(data=b64_data)

# Function I need:
#image = image.resize((100, 100), Image.ANTIALIAS)

label = tkinter.Label(image=image)
label.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

If there's a completely different way I can achieve this, I'd like to hear it.

Comment: Did u search for the solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Image resize under PhotoImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6582387/image-resize-under-photoimage)

Comment: @user1767754  No antialiasing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, well you first use PIL and then use PIL's TKinter Format to convert it to a TKinter Image. I don't have the `urllib` on my system so I've used Requests, but that part should be exchangeable.

```
import tkinter
import base64
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

import requests
from PIL import Image
from StringIO import StringIO
url = "https://s.yimg.com/os/weather/1.0.1/shadow_icon/60x60/partly_cloudy_night@2x.png"
r = requests.get(url)
pilImage = Image.open(StringIO(r.content))
pilImage.resize((100, 100), Image.ANTIALIAS)

window = tkinter.Tk()


image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(pilImage)

label = tkinter.Label(image=image)
label.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

There is one whole page dedicated for PIL and Tkinter: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm

Comment: I edited this code a bit and posted a comment. Thank you very much for helping me.

Answer (score 2):

I edited @user1767754 code since I had some problems with it, but it did help me greatly.

Note: I used BytesIO instead of StringIO. Also, I added image mode to 'RGBA' since I have problems when displaying grey-scale images. Also, minor fixes.

Code:

```
import tkinter
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from io import BytesIO
import requests

window = tkinter.Tk()

url = "https://s.yimg.com/os/weather/1.0.1/shadow_icon/60x60/partly_cloudy_night@2x.png"
r = requests.get(url)

pilImage = Image.open(BytesIO(r.content))
pilImage.mode = 'RGBA'
pilImage = pilImage.resize((50, 50), Image.ANTIALIAS)


image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(pilImage)

label = tkinter.Label(image=image)
label.pack()

window.mainloop()
```