# PhotoImage zoom

Tags: python, tkinter, zooming, photoimage

I'm trying to zoom in on an image and display it with the following code

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image as PIL_image, ImageTk as PIL_imagetk

window = tk.Tk()

img1 = PIL_imagetk.PhotoImage(file="C:\\Two.jpg")
img1 = img1.zoom(2)

window.mainloop()
```

But python says `AttributeError: 'PhotoImage' object has no attribute 'zoom'`. There is a comment on a related post here:
[Image resize under PhotoImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6582387/image-resize-under-photoimage)
which says "PIL's PhotoImage does not implement zoom from Tkinter's PhotoImage (as well as some other methods)".

I think this means that I need to import something else into my code, but I'm not sure what. Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`img1` has no method `zoom`, however `img1._PhotoImage__photo` does. So just change your code to:

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image as PIL_image, ImageTk as PIL_imagetk

window = tk.Tk()

img1 = PIL_imagetk.PhotoImage(file="C:\\Two.jpg")
img1 = img1._PhotoImage__photo.zoom(2)

label =  tk.Label(window, image=img1)
label.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

By the way if you want to reduce the image you can use the method `subsample` `img1 = img1._PhotoImage__photo.subsample(2)` reduces the picture by half.

If you have a PIL Image, then you can use resize like following example:

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

window = tk.Tk()

image = Image.open('C:\\Two.jpg')
image = image.resize((200, 200), Image.ANTIALIAS)
img1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=image)

label = tk.Label(window, image=img1)
label.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

*Note I just import `Image` and `ImageTk`, see no need to rename to `PIL_image` and `PIL_imagetk`, which to me is only confusing*

Comment: Thanks. Is there some documentation that explains why I need to use `._PhotoImage__photo`? I have no idea how I could have worked that out myself...

Comment: It took me a bit to find the method by drilling down through the __dir__ (for example `.__PhotoImage__photo.__dir__()'). As it starts with an underscore this is actually meant as a private method and discouraged for public use.