# How do i resize a image which is in URL?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
imagelist=[]
with open("imagelink.txt") as url:
for url2 in url:
    if url2.strip():
        raw_data= urllib.request.urlopen(url2.strip()).read()
        im = ImageTk.PhotoImage(data=raw_data)
        result = maintext.image_create(0.0, image=im)
        imagelist.append(im)
```

So this is my code i am opening a image URL and displaying the image in a text box,so how do I resize the image from the URL I tried using resize function but it says photo image doesn't have resize function.So how do I resize the URL image?

Comment: (1) Download the data from the URL (2) Load the data into a Pillow Image object (not an ImageTk.PhotoImage) (3) Resize the Pillow image (4) Make a ImageTk.PhotoImage out of the Pillow image.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38241889/13145954) may help, and explains how to manipulate a PhotoImage directly.

Comment: @Seon when i follwed that i get an error AttributeError: 'PhotoImage' object has no attribute 'zoom'

Comment: Write the data to a file and load the data with `PIL.Image()` then manipulate, then load for tkinter

Comment: @CoolCloud There is no other way where i can directly resize?if you have please write the code so that i can easily get it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `PIL.Image.open()` and `io.BytesIO()` to open and resize the retrieved image:

```
import io
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
...
imagelist=[]
with open("imagelink.txt") as url:
    for url2 in url:
        url2 = url2.strip()
        if url2:
            raw_data = urllib.request.urlopen(url2).read()
            # open the image and resize
            im = Image.open(io.BytesIO(raw_data)).resize((300,100))
            im = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)
            #im = ImageTk.PhotoImage(data=raw_data)
            result = maintext.image_create(0.0, image=im)
            imagelist.append(im)
```

Comment: Thank you thank you very much i am lucky that you solved my problem