# How can I resize an image in tkinter without pillow with no degradation

Tags: python, image, tkinter

I would like to resize or rotate images in tkinter without pillow and other libraries.

I have read this question and the answers:
[Image resize under PhotoImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6582387/image-resize-under-photoimage) ==> But

- I don't want use PILLOW
- zoom() and subsample() don't answer to rotate image.

I use this code to resize with or without "color_transparent" color in Python 2 and 3:

```
newPhotoImage = tk.PhotoImage(width=newWidth, height=newHeight)
for x in range(newWidth):
    for y in range(newHeight):
        xOld = int(x*oldWidth/newWidth)
        yOld = int(y*oldHeight/newHeight)
        ## ne marche pas en python 2 ==> rgb = '#%02x%02x%02x' % img.get(xOld, yOld)
        try:
            ## transforme un tupple de 3 valeurs rgb en valeur hexa
            rgb = '#%02x%02x%02x' % img.get(xOld, yOld)
        except TypeError:
            tt = img.get(xOld,yOld)      ## ==> 3 valeurs (unicode) pixel but not tuple
            # print (tt)
            # print (type (tt))
            tt1 = tuple(map(int, tt.split(" ")))
            rgb = '#%02x%02x%02x'%tt1

        ##newPhotoImage.put(rgb, (x, y))       ## marche mieux sur les icones noir et blanc ?
        if rgb != color_transparent:           ## on teste color transparente ici le noir "#000000"
            newPhotoImage.put(rgb, (x, y))
```

You have degradation:

- if you use color_transparent to black in the code you loose black color
- if your image is black and white rest just white
- if you don't use color_transparent the backgroud turns black with image

You have the possibility to use zoom() and subsample() it's work to resize (I don't find code?), but if you rotate you will have the same problem.

I know you have some libraries to do that, but I'd like to understand.

What is the best way to improve that?

Comment: "I don't want use PILLOW"—why not?

Comment: Because I learn python/tkinter without external library. And I would like to know how the code works for example in Photoimage zoom() and subsample(). And perhaps the code in Pillow...

Comment: Get used to the fact that you won't always understand every little detail of how your application works. It's _much_ better to use something like Pillow here.

Comment: Ok I've been working with Pillow.  but how Pillow do with the color_transparent ?